# How to get mongo results with matching condition along with verification of ceratain id in an embedded document array

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to display all matching records based on a certain condition along with that I need to check whether certain user existed or not in the nested array of each record along with the count of registered users (nested array count).

My Sample Collection Example :

```
"_id" : ObjectId("583fb6c9e17e8c1bf80da30e"),
"name" : "Arijt Singh Live",
"category" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("583dace6e17e4db43e29dd44"),
    "name" : "Music"
},
"schedule" : {
    "date" : ISODate("2016-12-16T03:30:00.000Z"),
    "start_time" : ISODate("2016-12-16T03:30:00.000Z"),
    "end_time" : ISODate("2016-12-16T10:30:00.000Z")
},
"celebrity" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("583dac6ee17e4db43e29dd3e"),
    "name" : "Chiranjeevi",
    "profilePic" : "http://sample.com/"
},
"online_moderator" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("583dac9ce17e4db43e29dd40"),
    "name" : "Suma",
    "profilePic" : "http://sample.com/",
    "id" : ObjectId("583dac9ce17e4db43e29dd40")
},
"offline_moderator" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("583daebae17e4db43e29dd48"),
    "name" : "PriyaRam",
    "roomUrl" : "http://sample.com/link",
    "roomName" : "PriyaRam_1480437433704",
    "roomKey" : "uJcJqV5D8j",
    "roomId" : "146547",
    "profilePic" : "http://sample.com/",
    "id" : ObjectId("583daebae17e4db43e29dd48")
},
"region" : {
    "code" : "IN",
    "name" : "India"
},
"status" : "active",
"event_state" : "live",
"registered_users" : [ 
    {
        "user_id" : ObjectId("583dac6ee17e4db43e29dd3e"),
        "user_name" : "Chiranjeevi",
        "profile_pic" : "http://sample.com/",
        "registered_date" : ISODate("2016-12-01T05:36:00.000Z"),
        "is_celebrity" : "true",
        "event_default_user" : "true",
        "user_call_status" : "joined",
        "audio_status" : "false",
        "video_status" : "false"
    }, 
    {
        "user_id" : ObjectId("583dac9ce17e4db43e29dd40"),
        "user_name" : "Suma",
        "profile_pic" : "http://sample.com/",
        "registered_date" : ISODate("2016-12-01T05:36:00.000Z"),
        "is_celebrity" : "false",
        "event_default_user" : "true",
        "user_call_status" : "registered",
        "audio_status" : "false",
        "video_status" : "false"
    }, 
    {
        "user_id" : ObjectId("583daebae17e4db43e29dd48"),
        "user_name" : "PriyaRam",
        "profile_pic" : "http://sample.com/",
        "registered_date" : ISODate("2016-12-01T05:36:00.000Z"),
        "is_celebrity" : "false",
        "event_default_user" : "true",
        "user_call_status" : "registered",
        "audio_status" : "false",
        "video_status" : "false"
    }, 
    {
        "user_id" : ObjectId("583e9719e17e8c1bf80da2fe"),
        "user_name" : "UserSurya",
        "profile_pic" : "siri",
        "registered_date" : ISODate("2016-11-30T12:32:00.000Z"),
        "is_celebrity" : "false",
        "event_default_user" : "false",
        "user_call_status" : "joined",
        "audio_status" : "false",
        "video_status" : "false",
        "participantId" : ""
    },  
    {
        "user_id" : ObjectId("584a47abe17e6e3ee8d7c645"),
        "user_name" : "Given",
        "profile_pic" : "asset.JPG",
        "registered_date" : ISODate("2016-12-09T06:07:00.000Z"),
        "is_celebrity" : "false",
        "event_default_user" : "false",
        "user_call_status" : "registered",
        "audio_status" : "false",
        "video_status" : "false"
    }, 
    {
        "user_id" : ObjectId("584e6253e17ed10f0a8cba1d"),
        "user_name" : "Manoj",
        "profile_pic" : "(null)",
        "registered_date" : ISODate("2016-12-12T08:40:00.000Z"),
        "is_celebrity" : "false",
        "event_default_user" : "false",
        "user_call_status" : "registered",
        "audio_status" : "false",
        "video_status" : "false"
    }
],
"recorder_id" : "269894",
"webcast_url" : "http://sample.com/link"
```

I have written the following query:

```
db.events.aggregate([
    { $match: { $and: [ 
        { "event_state" : {$in : ["live","scheduled"]} }, 
        { "schedule.end_time" : {$gt : ISODate("2016-12-12T06:30:00.000Z")} }
        ] 
      } 
    },
    {$project: 
        { 
            "name" :1, 
            "category" :1,
            "schedule":1, 
            "celebrity" :1,
            "online_moderator" :1,
            "offline_moderator" :1,
            "region" :1,
            "status" :1,
            "event_state" :1,
            "recorder_id" :1,
            "webcast_url":1,
            "replay_url":1,
            "registered_users":1,
            registeredUsers: { $size:"$registered_users" },
            is_registered:
               {
                 $cond: { if: { $eq: [ "registered_users.user_id", ObjectId("584e6253e17ed10f0a8cba1d") ] }, then: 1, else: 0 }
               }
        }
    }
]);
```

It gives me the partial result of what I really looking for.

In the above example If I need to check the user with Id registered for this event or not, then my query should return the result set along with the registration status like below.

```
"_id" : ObjectId("583fb6c9e17e8c1bf80da30e"),
    "name" : "Arijt Singh Live",
    "category" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("583dace6e17e4db43e29dd44"),
        "name" : "Music"
    },
    "schedule" : {
        "date" : ISODate("2016-12-16T03:30:00.000Z"),
        "start_time" : ISODate("2016-12-16T03:30:00.000Z"),
        "end_time" : ISODate("2016-12-16T10:30:00.000Z")
    },
    "celebrity" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("583dac6ee17e4db43e29dd3e"),
        "name" : "Chiranjeevi",
        "profilePic" : "http://sample.com/app/uploads/profilepics/"
    },
    "online_moderator" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("583dac9ce17e4db43e29dd40"),
        "name" : "Suma",
        "profilePic" : "http://sample.com/app/uploads/profilepics/",
        "id" : ObjectId("583dac9ce17e4db43e29dd40")
    },
    "offline_moderator" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("583daebae17e4db43e29dd48"),
        "name" : "PriyaRam",
        "roomUrl" : "http://sample.com/link",
        "roomName" : "PriyaRam_1480437433704",
        "roomKey" : "uJcJqV5D8j",
        "roomId" : "146547",
        "profilePic" : "http://sample.com/app/uploads/profilepics/",
        "id" : ObjectId("583daebae17e4db43e29dd48")
    },
    "region" : {
        "code" : "IN",
        "name" : "India"
    },
    "status" : "active",
    "event_state" : "live",    
    "recorder_id" : "269894",
    "webcast_url" : "http://sample.com/link",
    "registeredUsers" : 9,
    "is_registered": 1
```

In the above example, if you see "registeredUsers" and "is_registered" are not part of the original document. But I am trying to fetch that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is_registered field can be computed by adding the below expression in the $project stage. Makes use of ***[$setIsSubset](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/)*** by comparing two arrays and returns true when the first array is a subset of the second.

```
is_registered:
           { $setIsSubset: [[ObjectId("584e6253e17ed10f0a8cba1d")], "$registered_users.user_id"]}
```